# sync two folders mac os x el capitan

Tags: mac, sync

I have my keynote presentations in a dropbox folder. However, at work they´ve removed the dropbox option and also I see that I can use the keynote online app. Is there any way I can sync from the dropbox folder to the icloud drive folder and also the other way around so that the two folders are always mirrors of each other?

I´ve tried using 
`ln -s 'dropbox-keynote-folder'` when in the icloud drive folder with success. Now I´d like to also do the same from the dropbox folder, however the folder is already present and I dont want to remove it (fear of instant sync and all of a sudden without any folders - maybe I could do a three-way sync?).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try data synchronisation apps:

Paid ones:

- **DSync** - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dsync-easy-synchronization/id797512958?mt=12
- **Sync Folders Pro** - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sync-folders-pro/id522706442?mt=12

Free:

- **Sync Folder** - it's also available in App Store. It's a restricted version of Pro edition, but it's fully usable.

I was using Sync Folders (Free and Pro) for some time, and I think it's a quite nice tool.

Good luck